# getting POST using URLRequest + if statement syntax issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to get the reply from the address specified in var url:String, which is either 0 or 1. If the reply is 1 then it must set currentState = CallFailed (as seen below). The client compiles without error (using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6) and seems to successfully reach var url:String, but doesn't seem to be getting the response\and or my if statement is incorrect.

**Actionscript:**

```
            // check to see if block.php replies 0 or 1

            var url:String = "https://domain.com/block.php?postid=" + calleeInput.text + "";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            request.data = variables;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            navigateToURL(request);

            if (request.data == 1)
            {   

            // if reply is 1 then cancel the call   
            currentState = CallFailed;
            return;
            }
```

**PHP:**

PHP will echo 0 or 1 when block.php is loaded. It's not encoded in any format such as JSON\AJAX.

Comment: I reverted your last edit. Please do not "correct" the question by copying the solution over from the accepted answer. It's confusing for people who read this later. Nobody can understand what the original problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want data from the server.  Perhaps the URLLoader class would be better?

```
        var url:String = "https://domain.com/block.php?postid=" + calleeInput.text + "";
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        request.data = variables;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();         
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE,
            function( e:Event ) : void
            {
                // your response data will be here
                // you'll have to verify the format
                trace( e.target.data );
            }
        )
        loader.load( request );
```

Put a breakpoint at the trace statement and check out the contents of e.target.data, and go from there

Comment: I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: So the data for the if statement is stored in e.target.data? I updated the code above.

Comment: As per my example, it's in e.target.data.  "Event" is a class, and "e" is an actual Object with data.  In your case, "e" holds all the relevant data.  Your "if" statement will need to look into e.target.data, as in the example.

Comment: It looks like you might want to do a little reading up on how Actionscript variables are created.  In a nutshell, it goes `var nameOfInstance:NameOfClass = new NameOfClass()`, and in function signatures it goes `( nameOfInstance:NameOfClass )`

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html

Comment: Thanks I'm reading it over. Can you update your example with the correct if statement so I can have a clearer visual. It's more than just finding the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89484/discussion-between-michelle-and-joseph).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of [`navigateToURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) is to open the webbrowser, as stated in its documentation:

> Opens or replaces a window in the application that contains the Flash Player container (usually a browser). In Adobe AIR, the function opens a URL in the default system web browser

In order to perform an request (without opening a browser, just the HTTP communication) you should use [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).

> The URLLoader class downloads data from a URL as text, binary data, or URL-encoded variables.

---

On a related note: your logic is not valid. The call to a server is asynchronous. You have to wait for the response to be returned before reasoning about the result.

The `URLLoader` class dispatches a number of Events that help you decide when the result of a request is returned or if there's a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I'll research this now.